# Stunnel enable compression

Tags: compression, zlib, stunnel

Sounds like stunnel supports only two compression methods, based on their documentation: https://www.stunnel.org/static/stunnel.html

compression = deflate | zlib

So I'm trying to get zlib to work for example.

First I tried using the package of stunnel which I installed using `apt` (Ubuntu 22)
But when running the config I got:
`Configured compression is unsupported by OpenSSL`

Then I search for a while and found maybe that `apt` package doesn't support zlib, so I tried to build stunnel myself.

Yet again I didn't find any useful information on how to do that I can't find the right flag, I tried all the flags I could have thought of:

```bash
./configure --enable-system-zlib --with-included-zlib --with-system-zlib --with-zlib
```

But all of them were wrong:
`configure: WARNING: unrecognized options: --enable-system-zlib, --with-included-zlib, --with-system-zlib, --with-zlib`

Why can't we find a simple tutorial on how to do this?
That's why I had to ask this question!